# Soft Real Time App with Erlang

Tags: erlang, instant-messaging

I recently started learning Erlang and at this point I'm comfortable with most concepts and syntax. I'd like to continue my learning by using Erlang to build a "simple" instant message application. I'd appreciate suggestions on which resources (books, websites, etc.) can help me along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Learn You Some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content) has a bunch of chapters on concurrency, networking, and OTP.  You might also be interested in reading the [ejabberd](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd) code, though it might be a bit involved.

Comment: ejabberd is a rather complex, do you know of any simpler instant messaging examples?

Comment: Not specifically, but you can find some great reading material just by browsing around GitHub under the [Erlang section](https://github.com/languages/Erlang).